# Can a non-gallery SAML application in Azure Active Directory support both IDP and SP Initiated flows?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications), if the "Sign On URL" field is populated, the application acts as an SP Initiated flow.

If empty, it acts as an IDP Initiated flow.

In other words, it's either one or the other.

But e.g. in ADFS, the same SP can be both at the same time depending on whether you start with the application (SP Initiated) or the ADFS IDP Initiated page (IDP Initiated).

Is there any way to do this in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes.

If the "Sign On URL" is blank, invoking the application from myapps leads to the IDPInitiated flow.

For SP Initiated, you cannot use myapps. You have to start with the URL of the application i.e. outside of Azure AD.

If the "Sign On URL" is not blank, invoking the application from myapps leads to the SPInitiated flow. Azure AD will redirect to the application login page.

In this scenario, you cannot use the IDPInitiated flow.